# adb push not working on /system, read only

Tags: adb, file-system

I can do `adb push` to `/sdcard/` location but not `/system` on my android device.

```
sudo adb push lib/audio.primary.gmin.so system/lib/hw/
failed to copy 'lib/audio.primary.gmin.so' to 'system/lib/hw/audio.primary.gmin.so': Read-only file system
```

I tried some suggestions online

```
user$ adb remount
dm_verity is enabled on the system partition.
Use "adb disable-verity" to disable verity.
If you do not, remount may succeed, however, you will still not be able to write to these volumes.
remount of /system failed: Read-only file system
remount failed
user$ adb disable-verity
Verity already disabled on /system
```

Even after this, remount fails

```
user$ adb remount
dm_verity is enabled on the system partition.
Use "adb disable-verity" to disable verity.
If you do not, remount may succeed, however, you will still not be able to write to these volumes.
remount of /system failed: Read-only file system
remount failed
```

running below command on PC also does not work

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /system
mount: can't find /system in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab
```

**What should I do?**

EDIT.

```
   which mount
    /bin/mount

adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32
```

The output of mount command is as below

```
user$ mount
/dev/sda6 on / type ext3 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /home/user/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=user)
/dev/sda5 on /media/Data type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda2 on /media/OS type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
```

Comment: What phone model, Android version please?

Comment: You have to root your device first.

Comment: And it doesn't help to run those `sudo mount` commands ***on your PC*** if you want to remount a partition *on your Android device* (the output from `mount` as well as `sudo mount -o remount,rw /system` clearly is *not* from the Android device, and your Linux machine doesn't have `/system`). You need to run those via ADB *on the device*, e.g. `adb shell 'su -c "sudo mount -o remount,rw /system"'`. As Vahid correctly pointed out, that requires your device to be rooted.

Comment: Thanks for help. Yes the device is already rooted. It is working now after I did reboot the device after running `adb disable-verity`. So a reboot is must it seems. After reboot the `adb remount` command works fine.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The sequence of commands that worked for me was

```
adb root
adb disable-verity
adb reboot
adb root
adb remount
```

If I don't reboot, remount does not succeed.

Comment: only the mouse become invisible happen here, not disabling the mouse

Comment: adb disable-verity gives me an error of `error: closed`. Is there a reason/fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same trouble, no access to my Download folder from TWRP. BUT I did realize a folder that for me was not read-only. Try pushing to /data/local/tmp:
./adb push fileToPush /data/local/tmp

At first I was able to push to /sideload as well, but then all of a sudden it became read-only, so somehow I found this tmp a post online mentioning this tmp folder, and for me it was writeable.  Good luck!