# Can I edit the hosts file on my android without root access?

Tags: root-access, google-pixel, hosts

I'd like to block access to websites on my Pixel 3 android device. The parental settings leave much to be desired and apps like BlockSite don't work across all browsers. (In this case - it doesn't work in firefox)

Here's what I tried so far

```
adb pull /system/etc/hosts ~/Documents/android/hosts
```

I edited the hosts file and got it ready to be transferred back.

```
adb push ~/Documents/android/hosts /system/hosts
```

This gave me error message: `adb: error: failed to copy '/Users/[username]/Documents/android/hosts' to '/system/hosts': remote couldn't create file: Read-only file system`

Per this [post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/162902/adb-push-not-working-on-system-read-only) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066030/read-only-file-system-on-android), I tried a few other options.

I tried to use these commands

```
adb root
adb disable-verity
adb reboot
adb root
adb remount
```

This gave me error message: `adbd cannot run as root in production builds` and when I tried `adb disable-verity` it said: `verity cannot be disabled/enabled - USER build`.

I tried to use this command

```
adp remount
```

This gave me error: `Not running as root. Try "adb root" first.`

I downloaded an emulator and tried this command on my device

```
mount -o rw,remount /system
mount -o ro,remount /system
```

Similarly, this was unsuccessful

Comment: https://www.xda-developers.com/google-pixel-3-unlock-bootloader-root-magisk

Comment: https://adaway.org (for systemless hosts)

Comment: Can I update the `hosts` file without rooting the device?

Comment: Cauder, I saw https://www.modmy.com/how-modify-hosts-file-your-android-device and was about to try it but then saw your post here and got discouraged. Did you ever get it working without rooting? Thanks.