# AVD adb push gapps

Tags: adb, android-emulator, gapps

i try to get gapps working on my avd. I already use a google api image, but anyway the store is missing. Every tutorial tells me to push open gapps via adb:
https://medium.com/@dai_shi/installing-google-play-services-on-an-android-studio-emulator-fffceb2c28a1

But i have the problem, that system is not writable. I already tried various solutions like this one:
[adb push not working on /system, read only](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/162902/adb-push-not-working-on-system-read-only)

Finally i think this can be the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49426174/cannot-push-to-android-emulator-because-of-read-only-file-system/49427040

But my problem now is, that the emulator only shows a black screen when i use the -writable-system option. Otherwise it starts fine.

Can someone help me to get the store apk installed on my virtual device?

Comment: do you have any cmd line access while on black screen? i guess `-writable-system` is requirement (which is according to your linked researches only available API < 28)

Comment: adb says device offline. But it's API 29. So maybe this is the problem

Comment: i tried with API 27, it's still the same. Screen remains black
```emulator @Nokia_8 -writable-system
emulator: WARNING: System image is writable
Failed to open /qemu.conf, err: 2
Windows Hypervisor Platform accelerator is operational```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50604060/android-emulator-with-hyper-v

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25241380/it-seems-too-many-emulator-instances-are-running-on-this-machine-aborting

Comment: i tried the solutions, but non worked @alecxs
```D:\>emulator @Nokia_8  -writable-system -no-audio -gpu guest
emulator: WARNING: System image is writable
emulator: WARNING: Your AVD has been configured with an in-guest renderer, but the system image does not support guest rendering.Falling back to 'swiftshader_indirect' mode.
emulator: ERROR: VkCommonOperations.cpp:541: Failed to create Vulkan instance.
Failed to open /qemu.conf, err: 2
Windows Hypervisor Platform accelerator is operational
```